# Android admob mediation custom ad listener

Tags: android, admob

I am using a custom ad listener in my android app with admob mediation. Admob allows me to either show the custom ad first or the admob ad first. How can I define a certain percentage of times when the custom ad is shown i.e. Custom ad should be shown only x% of times of total, else AdMob ad should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anyway to do this.

Admob mediation will attempt to maximise your earnings by ordering the ad networks based on expected eCPM and calling each in turn asking for an ad. The first ad network that responds is the one whose ad will be shown.